# Sending MDM Payload to APNS with Python

Tags: python, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am trying to test the MDM capabilities in iOS. I have installed the profile on the device now I am not able to send the `{"mdm":"PushMagicValue"}` to the device.
Can some please provide the python code to do this. Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Try [PyAPNs](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs). You need to set up your app on developer.apple.com to use APN and use correct keys.

Comment: :which key I should use to send the push notifications. I have another issue that I have not got any private key associated with my APNS certificate generated on the https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/

Comment: Make sure you follow the steps listed on http://highonpython.com/index.php/setting-up-ios-push-notifications-apns-with-pythondjango-through-pyapns/

Comment: it is not able to send mdm payload

Comment: Is there any way to know about what has APNS has sent to our device?